# jQuery: How to get the width sum of all previous elements and put it in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get the width of each previous elements and sum them up (after page load)
Then put the value in each  element data attribute
This is the code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jSfKJ/2/
so how to make this code

```
<ul>
 <li style="width:130px">Num 1</li>
 <li style="width:150px">Num 2</li>
 <li style="width:140px">Num 3</li>
 <li style="width:175px">Num 4</li>
 <li style="width:100px">Num 5</li>
</ul>
```

to be like this

```
<ul>
 <li style="width:130px" data-num="0">Num 1</li>
 <li style="width:150px" data-num="130">Num 2</li>
 <li style="width:140px" data-num="280">Num 3</li>
 <li style="width:175px" data-num="420">Num 4</li>
 <li style="width:100px" data-num="595">Num 5</li>
</ul>
```

This image to explain more clearly what I want 
[image]

I hope I've explained what I want well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to do it is like that : http://jsfiddle.net/jSfKJ/5/

you save a var an add the width of the element in the each :

```
(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('li').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('data-num', total)
        total += $(this).width()
    });
})();
```

This method allow you to reduce the number of `each` to 1

Comment: Well spotted. I would use .data("num",total) instead of attr

Comment: I personally would to, but he said he wanted a DOM like that : `<li style="width:130px" data-num="0">Num 1</li>`. If i am not wrong, `data` doesnt update the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
var globalheight = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        $(this).attr({'data-num':globalheight}); 
        globalheight = globalheight+$(this).width();
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate as you have there in your fiddle something like the following:

```
var ctr = 0;
$('li').each(function() {
    var itm = $(this);
    itm.data().num = ctr;
    ctr += itm.width();
});
// below just to show u the output.
$('li').each(function (){
    console.log($(this).data());  
});
```

It is unclear if you want it save to data or if you want it to be an actual attribute visible in the markup. If visible just add each as itm.attr('num', ctr);